# Trying to run Appium Inspector on Windows

Tags: python

Failed to create session. An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot verify the signature of 'C:\Users\Ammar\AppData\Local\Temp\2022115-15644-1s5wrs0.ozyri\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.24.0.apk'. Original error: The JAVA_HOME location 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.1\bin' must exist[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sq7JM.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue.

UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Cannot verify the signature of 'C:\Users...\appium-uiautomator2-server-v4.24.0.apk'. Original error: The JAVA_HOME location 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_301' must exist

I resolved it by setting the correct JAVA_HOME variable in Appium.
The issue was that in my C:\Program Files\Java there was jre1.8.0_321
In Appium it was jre1.8.0_301 and I set it to jre1.8.0_321

I have change it here and it works for me:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON0mJ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyidz.png)